# Boto3 - delete all items with a specific partition key

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table with a partition key and sort key.

I would like to delete all items that belong to a partition key. But when I call delete_item with only the partition key it doesn't work:

```
table.delete_item(Key={"user_id": "xx"})
```

I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Comment: " it doesn't work" - what does it mean? Any error? Your question lacks details and is unclear. You have to describe precisely, what is happening? How to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Well, what is the schema? Again, not enough details.

Comment: @Marcin I have a partition key called "user_id" and a sort key "customer_id". I would like to delete all rows with the partition key "xx"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to delete all rows with the partition key "xx"

Not possible. Your key is partition key + sort key, which means that you always have to **use both keys** to identify your elements. So you have to get the full list of IDs (partition + sort key) and then iterate over them to delete the elements, or use [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) for one API call.